# Вино рОзлито или все-таки рАзлито?

Tags: морфология, гласные

Проясните, пожалуйста, существующую норму. Слово "розлив" как профессиональный жаргон вроде бы стало уже литературным. А образованное от него "розлито"? И как ставить ударения в словах "разлито" и "розлито"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Розлив, как и разлив образовано от глагола разлить (чередование приставок раз-роз). В инфинитиве "розлить" звучит как-то уж совсем не по-русски, и в словарях вы его не найдёте. Однако формы от этого глагола используются в качестве профессионального сленга. Если брать в расчёт этот сленг, то тут действует общий принцип для приставок раз-роз, под ударением "о" - без ударения "а".

Answer (score 4):

"Р**о**злив" — это, прежде всего, профессиональный термин. Литературно все равно будет "вино на разлив", но виноделы и виноторговцы говорят и пишут "р**о**злив". Это примерно, как "кОмпас" и "КомпАс".

Comment: Меня интересует в первую очередь оформление текста в этикетках продукции. Слово "розлив" мы используем повсеместно, насчет него сомнений нет. Но встретилось еще и "розлито". Наверно, стоит его избегать и заменять на "разлито", так как нормативность "розлито" под большим вопросом.

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki,

> Это примерно, как "кОмпас" и "КомпАс"

да, но тут только лишь ударение смещается, при постоянстве написания, а в данном вопросе речь именно о правописании...

Answer (score 3):

Если речь про то, что вино пролито на пол, то однозначно *рАзлито*.
Если же речь про рОзлив в тару — то тут уже можно аргументировать, но я бы все равно склонялся к версии, что нужно писать "разлито".

Касательно ударения — меня напрягает, но в орфоэпическом словаре не нашел ни первого слова, ни второго.

P.S. [**Словарь**](http://www.e-reading-lib.org/bookreader.php/134627/Reznichenko_-_Orfoepicheskiii_slovar'_russkogo_yazyka.pdf) дает **разлИто**, что вполне ожидаемо.

Comment: Согласна, "разлИто" - сомнений нет. А как произносить "розлито": рОзлито" тогда? От рОзлив.

Answer (score 1):

А мне кажется, что на "профессиональный сленг" ссылаются только по той причине, что 90% населения в стране безграмотны и проще подогнать правила русского языка под баранов, чем баранов научить правилам русского языка.
Когда я учился, приставки "роз" не было и, к слову, "кофе" был мужского рода.

Answer (score 1):

РОзлив - употребляется только в профессиональной речи, это указывается в словарях. Но ни один орфоэпический словарь, ни новый, ни старый, не разрешал форму "рОзлито", только "разлИто".